# Azure storage account - encryption

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I would like to encrypt storage account, I want to use option ***Customer-managed keys*** in the Encryption type section. Once I do this I can see in ***Automated key rotation*** value ***Enabled - Using the latest key version***. I dont want to use Automated Key rotation, how can I disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the `Automated key rotation`, please follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the keyvault in the portal -> `Keys` -> click the key -> click the version you want to use -> copy the `Key Identifier` like below.

[image]

2.Navigate to the storage account -> `Encryption` -> `Change key` -> `Enter key URI` -> use the one got in step 1 -> Save.

[image]

Then the `Automated key rotation` will be disabled.

[image]